# Drawing 3 of a kind in a 7 card hand

Tags: probability, poker

I have a probability question if anyone is willing to help. In a $7$ card hand without replacement what is the probability of getting at least a $3$ of a kind (standard deck A-K, $4$ suits). I was trying to look into it and the working equation I have so far is:

$$\frac{{13\choose 1} \times  {4\choose 3} \times {13\choose 4} \times {4\choose 1} \times {4\choose 1} \times {4\choose 1} \times {4\choose 1}}{52\choose 7} $$

I can't even really explain how I got that I was just trying numbers to try to get close to the value I arrived at experimentally which seems to be closer to $7.69\%$ instead of $7.11\%$ which is what the combination formula gives me.

Any help would be appreciated I just really want to get a better understanding of this specific case without having to go through a whole probability course.

Comment: Exactly three of a kind?  Can you have *two* threes-of-a-kind?  If you have four of a kind, does that count as having a three-of-a-kind? ....

Comment: Yeah I should have specified. I was hoping to find out the probability inclusive of all those other things. So 4 of a kind would count as would two three-of-a-kind pairs. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The value you calculated was the probability of one rank having three cards of that rank, and correcting the next term to $\binom{12}{4}$ instead the remaining cards all being of different ranks, not only different than the first but also different than each other.

Comment: You won't arrive at an answer purely via rule of product here.  You might consider listing out cases for distributions of cards: 4-3, 4-2-1, 4-1-1-1, 3-3-1, 3-2-2, 3-2-1-1, 3-1-1-1-1 and counting each of these separately.  Alternatively, you might try using inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply J.  It seems I may have jumped into something a little above my pay grade. I'll have to look into inclusion-exclusion as it's not anything I'm familiar with. It seems it’s a more complex problem than I initially thought.
I’m still trying to parse your first comment. You said what I found was the probability of one rank having 3 of that rank in that hand and I thought that was what I trying to solve. Are you saying I’m not accounting for cases where I have 4 of a kind or two pairs of 3 of a kind?

Comment: Anyway thanks again for the reply. I'll have to mull it over and do some more reading.

Comment: "*Are you saying I'm not accounting for cases where I have 4 of a kind or two pairs of 3 of a kind?*"  Yes.  Without the correction, you overcounted hands with a 4-of-a-kind (*having accidentally allowed for both an ace of spades in the first designated triple and again as a "kicker"*).  With and without the correction, having not allowed for any arrangement other than 3-1-1-1-1 (*or incorrectly 4-1-1-1*) and missed out on a second 3 of a kind or a pair in the off cards etc...